# Neo4j Lucene integration layer - does it support soundex/spelling capabilities?

Tags: lucene, neo4j

We are implementing text searching with wild cards using Lucene backed indices in Neo4j and would like to add soundex and spell checking capabilities. Has anyone done this? We would like to use the Neo4j Lucene integration layer so we can consolidate management of the Neo4j\Lucene indices and not use Solr or Lucene API directly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is done, but check out the extended Lucene APIs in Neo4j Indexes, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/indexing-lucene-extras.html